# Dreamweaver connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql, dreamweaver

I want to build a website using dreamweaver and mysql. I used mamp on mac to communicate with mysql.But when I try to build database connection with my sql, I got this error:

HTTP Error Code 404 File Not Found. Here are some possible reasons for the problem:

```
1) There is no testing server running on the server machine.
2) The testing server specified for this site does not map to the "http://localhost/LabelSite/_mmServerScripts/MMHTTPDB.php URL."Verify that the URL Prefix maps to the root of the site.
```

I googled and try a bunch of ways but none of them work.Here is what I've already tried:

```
1)copying MMHTTPDB.php and mysql.php to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/LabelSite/_mmServerScripts
2)changing the web url to "http://localhost/8888/LabelSite"
```

But none of them worked

Here is how I set my site by dreamweaver:
[image]

[image]

I did select server model to be "PHP MYSQL" on the advanced tag of Servers
Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing Web Url in the site's testing servers to

`"http://localhost:8888/LabelSite/"`

Now I get rid of the error！

Comment: In the [HTTP URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) the protocol can be defined after the host name part, separated with a `:`, and not with a `/` as you have figured it out.